# Rails redirect /images to /assets/images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

I have a static application file which requires all images to be available at `/images` path. But rails makes my `/images` folder available via `/assets/images`. How can I write redirect rule in `routes.rb` so that whenever someone asks `/images/1.png` he gets `/assets/images/1.png`?

Comment: have you tried /public/images ?

Comment: I placed /images in /public/images (on disk) and files are available at /assets/images (in browser)

Comment: I need something line mod_rewrite, but on rails level :)

Comment: In development, assets are provided by the pipeline in a development-transparent-path-oriented way. In production the paths will be different. You should stick with rails conventions so that you'll have no problem serving assets for both envs. You should check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html